# Show Phone Calls in SiteMap

Tags: android-activity, sitemap, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

If you link Phone calls in sitemap in CRM (nav_phonecalls), what it will link is to Activities view of phone calls (it will not have an fields specific to phone call itself and will show only generic Activity fields).

The proper Phone Call views are available if you drill down from Activities drop down above the grid, select Phone Call and one of phone call views.

Is it possible to link in sitemap so that by default it will show one of the views defined on Phone Call entity?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the Phone Call Entity on the site map as below will cause Phone Call views to display (not the activity views):

```xml
<SubArea Id="nav_phonecalls" Entity="phonecall">
   <Titles>
      <Title LCID="1033" Title="Phone Calls" />
   </Titles>
</SubArea>
```

I justed tested this and confirmed that this shows the phone call views, not the activity views.  If you want to default to a specific phone call view, that would be done at the entity level

Comment: Thanks for formatting the code jcjr, makes it much more readable